# iOS calendar list view on PHP web application

Tags: php, javascript, ios, html, web

As the title, I am trying to create a Calendar List View exactly like the iOS one on my PHP web application. Specifically, I am stuck at how to create the sectionized header dates that holds itself at the top as you scroll.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it with the CSS attribute "position: fixed" and give the rest of your table data some margin or padding on top.

Comment: hmmm ok... I'd imagine this solves the first date display. and how about when it reaches the next date, though?

Comment: I think i know what you mean. Implementing a "Scrollspy" mechanism would be the way to go i guess. Twitter Bootstrap has a good one (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) - also there's implementations for jQuery (https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy) and MooTools (http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy) - you probably have to tweak the CSS but the mechanism would be something along these lines...

Comment: That looks like it can solve my problem. I will go and try it. Thank you so much! :)